# How to user jQuery selector to get nth of this jQuery selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried:

```
$('.download a').first().attr('href')
```

This would give me correct result if the a link is indeed the first in `$('.download a')`

Both `$('.download a')[0]` and `$('.download a').get(0)` returns DOM object instead of jQuery object, therefore attr is not a function.

`$('.download a:nth-of-type(1)').attr('href')` works, but I want to know if there is a different way to do it. Maybe like `$('.download a').nth(1)`. This is purely for amusement purpose.

Comment: You can use a nasty trick: `$($('.download a').get(0))`. Now it's jQuery object and you can do `.attr('href')` on it ;)

Comment: `$('.download a').eq(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eq()` as a [method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_eq.asp):

```
$('.download a').eq(0).attr('href')
```

Or as a [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_eq.asp):

```
$('.download a:eq(0)').attr('href')
```

In this case the index numbers start at 0, so the first element will have the index number 0 (not 1).

Answer (score 3):

you can use [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get a jquery object

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use :nth-of-type(i), you can use .get(i) and then wrap the result in a jQuery selector:

```
var selection = $('.download a').get(0);

$(selection); // jQuery object
```

**EDIT:**

As Victor Radu mentions above, using the `.eq()` method is a much better solution.